# How to print a value from main-process to renderer's devtools in electron

Tags: javascript, debugging, electron, ipc, devtools

I want to print some object that is only available in main-process but i need to print that object in electron devtools so i can expand and explore it in devtools.

i used `console.log()` but this only prints object in terminal. Is there any work around like custom function with ipc running `myConsole.log("object")` in main-process and it prints in devtools?

Comment: What about this? Declare a variable at the top-level scope - let's say its `var myTest;`. Then, in the part of your code which contains the object you can't easily log to the console, do `myTest = your_object;` Later on, simply `console.log(myTest);' in the DevTools.

Comment: to do it with ipc, using win.once('did-finish-load', (object) => {//send message with object}), where win is the browser window launched from main.  in the renderer process, console log the object upon receiving it.   then open devtools in the browser window